# Dark gray desktop, GUI not started, vnc works fine

Tags: vnc

I installed tightvncserver and I configured it to start at boot.
Once this was done, restarting the RPI, the system was in login loop.. 
Following instruction on the web, I renamed the file .Xauthority and rebooted again. Now I have the vnc that is working fine, through my pc desktop I can see the gui of raspbian etc.. but the GUI is stucked on the RPI itself (looking the screen connected). Stucked means dark gray background with arrow pointer and the possibility to open rxterminal by right click..
How I can fix?
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I fixed.
It was simply starting as "openbox". I closed it and a normal login happears and luckely, inserting credentials the GUI with normal desktop started.
Sorry, was something new for me, and after 3 hours trying, I decided to write here.
Bye
Andrea